# Jest mocks and error handling - Jest test skips the "catch" of my function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm creating a jest test to test if metrics were logged for the error handling of the superFetch function. My approach is creating a mock function for retryFetch and returning a Promise reject event. I expect that to go to the superFetch catch but it keeps ending up in superFetch then. What can I do to handle my errors in superFetch catch?

These are the functions:

```
// file: fetches.js
export function retryFetch(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fetch(url).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                     resolve(response);
                     return;
                }
                throw new Error();
          }).catch(error => {
                createSomething(error).then(createSomething => {
                   reject(createSomething);
                });
                return;
          });
    });
});

export function superFetch(url, name, page) {
    return retryFetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            Metrics.logErrorMetric(name, page);
            throw error;
        });
}
```

My jest test:

```
import * as fetch from '../../src/utils/fetches';

    describe('Fetch fails', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            fetch.retryFetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Error')));
        });

        it('error metric is logged', () => {
            return fetch.superFetch('url', 'metric', 'page').then(data => {
                expect(data).toEqual(null);
                // received data is {"ok": true};
                // why is it even going here? im expecting it to go skip this and go to catch

            }).catch(error => {
                // this is completely skipped. but I'm expecting this to catch an error
                // received error is null, metric was not called
                expect(Metrics.logErrorMetric).toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(error).toEqual('Error');
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you overwrite the function in the exported module but `superFetch` use the original one inside of the module, so the overwrite will have no effect.

You could mock `fetch` directly like this:

```
global.fetch = jest.mock(()=> Promise.reject())
```